# find the points where the graph has a vertical tangent

Tags: calculus

can someone help me, please. I could not solve this question.

Find the points where the graph of $x^3+12xy+y^3=0 $ has a vertical tangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Use implicit differentiation and see when $y'$ has a value of $\pm \infty$